# System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException in mvc

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I am new to mvc. And I am getting System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException in mvc.

My Model file contains below code:

```
    using System;
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Linq; 
    using System.Web;

   namespace demomvc.Models
   {
     [Table("Employee")]
     public class Employee
     {
       [Key]
       public int EmployeeId {get;set;}
       public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
     }
     public class DbClass : DbContext
     {
       public DbSet<Employee> employee { get; set; }
     }
   }
```

My View Contains following Code:

```
     @model IEnumerable<demomvc.Models.Employee>
     @using demomvc.Models;
     @{
         ViewBag.Title = "Index";
      }

      <h2>Employee</h2>
      @foreach(Employee emp in @Model)
     {  
         <li>
       @emp.EmployeeId;
       @emp.EmployeeName;
        </li>
     }
```

Controller is:

[Error in Controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ogiHK.png)

Web.Config Code:

```
     <add name="DbClass" connectionString="Data Source=DIPS;
     Initial Catalog=dbo.Employee;Integrated Security=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

SQL server Image:

[SQL server Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VKWcZ.png)

Please help me to resolve a problem.

Comment: Try using username and password for the connection string `<add name="DbClass" connectionString="Data Source=DIPS;
     Initial Catalog=dbo.Employee;User ID=usernamehere;Password=passwordhere"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />`

Comment: i have provided UserID=sa;Password=dips .. But it is giving the same error

Comment: Make this virtual `public virtual DbSet<Employee> employee { get; set; }`

Comment: 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code. Keyword UserID is not supported.

Comment: Is `User ID=` not `UserID`.

Comment: <add name="DbClass" connectionString="Data Source=DIPS;Initial Catalog=dbo.Employee;Integrated Security=True;UserID=sa;Password=dips"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

Comment: `<add name="DbClass" connectionString="Data Source=DIPS;Initial Catalog=dips;User ID=sa;Password=dips" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />` the correct way.

Comment: wow. This is working. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

The connection string must point to your database, not to your table:

```
<add name="DbClass" connectionString="Data Source=DIPS;Initial Catalog=dips;User ID=sa;Password=dips" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Also mark the property as virtual::

```
public virtual DbSet<Employee> employee { get; set; }
```

Comment: Initial catlog value was wrong in my connection string. I don't understand why Dbset class is virtual.?

Comment: The `virtual` keyword is used to enable lazy loading mechanism as long as the dbcontext is alive. This means the employees will get loaded only when is required (or accessed). It's also common to use `virtual` for the testing purposes.